# MAUI: how to validate an entry field to be non empty and a valid e-mail

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I have an entry field that I need to validate to be non empty and a valid e-mail.

I used MAUI toolkit behaviors this way:

```
        <Entry x:Name="Email" MaxLength="50" Placeholder="Correo electrónico">
            <Entry.Behaviors>
                <toolkit:MultiValidationBehavior 
                    InvalidStyle="{StaticResource InvalidEntryStyle}"  
                    ValidStyle="{StaticResource ValidEntryStyle}"
                    Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged">

                    <toolkit:EmailValidationBehavior 
                            DecorationFlags="Trim,NullToEmpty"
                            Flags="ValidateOnValueChanged" 
                            MinimumLength="1"
                            MaximumLength="50"
                            toolkit:MultiValidationBehavior.Error="Debes ingresar el correo electrónico de forma correcta."  />
                </toolkit:MultiValidationBehavior>
            </Entry.Behaviors>
        </Entry>
```

The problem if nothing is entered in the field, `Email.Text` is null (even when I placed `NullToEmpty` decoration flag). In that case, the validation is successful.

when I add a character and then delete it, `Email.Text` is empty and the validation failed.

How can I handle this?

Comment: if none of the existing behaviors correctly handle null values, you could create your own.  Or you could try initializing the field to `String.Empty` instead of `null`

Comment: I did that, but since this a common task, I am wondering why the toolkit does not handle it.

Comment: choice 3, fix the behavior to correctly handle nulls and submit a PR to the repo

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ObservableValidator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observablevalidator) from `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` package. I made an easy demo.

This is the MainPageViewModel:

```
public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableValidator
{
    //[Required] attribute means it shouldn't be null
    //[EmailAddress] that's for email format

    [ObservableProperty]
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    private string email;


    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Validate();
    }


    [RelayCommand]
    void Validate()
    {
        ValidateAllProperties();
    }
}
```

For page, like the following:

```
<Entry x:Name="email" Text="{Binding Email,Mode=TwoWay}"
   ClearButtonVisibility="WhileEditing">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="TextChanged"
            Command="{Binding ValidateCommand}" />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
            <Entry.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry"
                         Binding="{Binding HasErrors}"
                         Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Entry"
                         Binding="{Binding HasErrors}"
                         Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Entry.Triggers>
</Entry>
```

So when the email text is not valid, the background color of entry would be red.

**Also you could define your own attributes.** For example, if you want to validate if the text of entry contains a space, you could define a NonSpace attribute:

```
public sealed class NonSpaceAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public NonSpaceAttribute()
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        int num = str.IndexOf(" ");

        if(num == -1)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
               
        return new("The current value includes space");
    }
}
```

Then just consume it:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NonSpace]
    [EmailAddress]    
    private string email;
```

Hope it helps!